# Is there any React plugin similar to jquery's infinitysliderv2 plugin?

Tags: reactjs, slider, carousel, infinite-scroll

I am looking for a react plugin to perform the same function as jquery's infinitysliderv2 plugin. Here is its demo page: https://wood-roots.com/sample/infiniteslidev2/
I spent hours google but couldn't find any such plugin. Anyone know something like that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you able to come across Swiper.js? They have a lot to offer when it comes to carousels and it also has a lot of properties too which you can add to your carousel for it to be fully-customizable. Here is the docs for reference. https://swiperjs.com/demos. For the AutoScrolling effect, you could use **Free mode& AutoPlay** to achieve that effect. Just look for the properties in the documentation. Hope this would help